# Installation error for Centos x64 running in VMware

Tags: installation, centos, vmware-workstation

I have just installed CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511 to my VMware. I tried to follow the [instructions at this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7).

I run `# yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"`

and it shows this:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Obvious question, but no mentioned in your post so asking anyways: Is the VM connected to a network. Is that working? Can it reach the Internet and more specifically the servers you are trying to download the GNOME desktop from ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is name resolving. Try to change, or add if not present, **NM_CONTROLLED** to **"no"** in the file etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-your_interface_name.

```
nano etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-your_interface_name
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
```

Then save it and restart your interface:

```
 ifdown your_interface_name
 ifup your_interface_name
```